# Storing and reading images from hbase

Tags: hbase

I want to store images in my hbase table.And I want to read the image file from hbase table as a image.Is it possible to do it in hbase.
Image size may not exceed 10MB.For each row there should be an image associated with it.Wondering how to do it.Need some clue hot to proceed.

Comment: Why not store images in HDFS and use HBase to store image meta-data?

Comment: Max file size(10MB) is less than hdfs block size. So, HDFS is not a good storage option. HDFS is known to have a limitation to scale beyond 400 million files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to store image in HBase and Read images directly from HBase table.
Store byte[] of an image in one column. You will be able to retrieve the image. Also, you can use http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_rest to retrieve the image. Just use this request header: "

> Accept: application/octet-stream

" 
We at [Truecar.com](https://www.truecar.com/#/) are using HBase to store millions of Images. Recently, we presented our use case at [Hadoop Summit 2015](http://2015.hadoopsummit.org/san-jose/agenda/). Soon, we will share slides and more details in a blogpost.

Also have a look at this enhancement HBase jira for storing images: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-11339

Here is an old presentation for storing image yfrom.com : http://www.slideshare.net/jacque74/hug-hbase-presentation

Comment: Thanks Anil..Got some idea how to store..Please let me know your slide ..sound interesting....

Comment: @Aman: I am not aware of your use case. You will also need to tune HBase for your workload.

Comment: Thanks Anil, this really helps me lot. Besides, cloudera provide the HBase version include 11339 fix, anyone interested can find more info here: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/admin_hbase_mob.html